# find all constraints using foreign key

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, persistence, hibernate-criteria

I have two entities viz:

State

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "State")
public class StateEntity {

   @Column(name = "id", length = 36, nullable = false, unique = true)
   private String id;

  @ManyToOne (fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "InsurerId", nullable = false)
  private InsurerEntity insurer;

  @Column(name ="StateName", length = 50, nullable = false)
  private String stateName;

//getters and setters

}
```

Insurer

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Insurer")
public class InsurerEntity {

  @Column(name = "InsurerId", length = 36, nullable = false, unique = true)
  private String insurerId;

  @Column(name = "InsurerName", length = 100, nullable = true)
  private String insurerName;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "state", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private List<StateEntity> stateEntityList;

//getters and setters

}
```

the insurer's id gets saved in state database as 'insurerid' and I want to retrieve it using hibernate criteria query but I can't seem to figure it out. It's easy to get foreign key using statename but when I try vice versa nothing works

I'm trying to execute this query: `SELECT StateName FROM Mydb.state where InsurerId='74'`

I tried this:1

```
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<StateEntity> findByForeignId(String id) {
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<StateEntity> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(StateEntity.class);
        Root<StateEntity> root = criteriaQuery.from(StateEntity.class);

        criteriaQuery = criteriaQuery.select(root).where(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("insurer"), id));
        try {
            return entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
        } catch (NoResultException nre) {
            return null;
        } catch (NonUniqueResultException nure) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

But it returns:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [74] did not match expected type [in.unlimitdigital.poleasy.entities.InsurerEntity (n/a)]
```

And:2

```
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<ModelEntity> findByForeignId(String id) {
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<ModelEntity> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(ModelEntity.class);
        Root<BrandEntity> root = criteriaQuery.from(BrandEntity.class);

        criteriaQuery = criteriaQuery.multiselect(root).where(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("id"), id));
        try {
            return entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
        } catch (NoResultException nre) {
            return null;
        } catch (NonUniqueResultException nure) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

it returns:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.SqlNode cannot be cast to org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.FromReferenceNode
```

Please help me with this...

Comment: Using a criteria query to do such a simple thing is not a good idea. `InsurerEntity insurer = em.find(id, InsurerEntity.class); List<StateEntity> states = insurer.getStateEntityList();`. Or using JPQL: `select state from StateEntity state where state.insurer.id = :id`. The root of your problem is explained in the exception message: you're trying to compare an ID with an entity. You can compare two entities, or two IDs. But not an entity and an ID.

Comment: You should also really learn about proper exception handling. Your two catch blocks do much more harm than good. You shouldn't have any catch block. Those two exceptions are never thrown by getResultList() anyway.

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you very much & I will consider your thoughts on this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you missed the `id` variable inside your `InsurerEntity` class.

**Change this line :**

```
criteriaQuery = criteriaQuery.select(root).where(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("insurer"), id));
```

**To this :**

```
criteriaQuery = criteriaQuery.select(root).where(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("insurer").get("id"), id));
```

Comment: Thank you very much @gnana for your effort, I really appreciate it

Comment: It's my pleasure.i'm glad to help you.